# Times a DC motor can be driven from pair of AAA 1000mAh

Tags: dc-motor, battery-operated

If I have 3V voltage made from two AAA in series, both 1000mAh and driving a 3V 1.5W DC motor with it, being the duration of tON exactly 1 second for each drive attempt. Is it possible to estimate the quantity of times the motor will trigger until the end of the baterry charge/capacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes, but battery voltages droop with discharge and motors' current varies with load. Also note that the 1000 mAh capacity will be at a certain load current, probably less than 100 mA. The datasheet will give you more information on that. You might get away with this though since your pulses are short.

The energy in your cells is given by volts × ampere-hours = 3 × 1 = 3 Wh.

Since there are 3600 s in one hour that gives you 3 × 3600 = 10,800 Ws (J or joules but Ws suits our purposes here).

Number of 1 s cycles = \$ \frac {Total \ Energy}{Energy/cycle} = \frac {10800\ \text{Ws}}{1.5\ \text W \times 1\ \text s} = 7200 \ \text {cycles} \$.

Comment: Hi. Why not 10.800 Ws insted of 3600 in your calculation?

Comment: It is now! Good work. It shows that you understood the answer.

Comment: Note that in addition to voltage droop, the motor takes several times its rated current while starting up. How quickly does it reach full speed? A second? In practice it may take 3W over that first second (or even more) giving 3600 operations or less.